# Parsing JSON - json array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have JSON like this:

```js
{  
   "cod":"200",
   "message":0.0085,
   "cnt":37,
   "list":[  
      {  
         "dt":1492074000,
         "main":{  
            "temp":8.74,
            "temp_min":8.39,
            "temp_max":8.74,
            "pressure":1002.4,
            "sea_level":1023.01,
            "grnd_level":1002.4,
            "humidity":94,
            "temp_kf":0.35
         },
         "weather":[  
            {  
               "id":500,
               "main":"Rain",
               "description":"Lekki deszcz",
               "icon":"10d"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{  
            "all":32
         },
(...)
```

And I have a problem to access String "description":"Lekki deszcz". If I use code like this:

```
JSON.parse(json.list[0]['weather'][0].description);
//OR
JSON.parse(json.list[0]['weather'][0]['description']);
```

I get nothing. But if I want to access int in this array "id":500, everything is okay.

```
JSON.parse(json.list[0]['weather'][0].id);
```

So it looks like a problem with parsing a String in this specific example.

Answer (score 2):

JSON.parse is only not throwing an error for `JSON.parse(500)` because you can use it on a number. You already have a json object (otherwise your line `JSON.parse(json.list[0]['weather'][0].id);` would fail too).

The output of JSON.parse(500) is 500:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(500))
```

However, when you try to JSON.parse non json, you get an error:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse("foo"))
```

That being said, you don't need JSON.parse at all, as it is only for, well ,parsing JSON. To get what you want, just use

```
console.log(json.list[0].weather[0].description);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to access the value of that property, there is on need for `JSON.parse`. It doesn't make sense to call `JSON.parse` on a property value to begin with...unless that value is a string interpretation of *more* JSON data.

A simple: `json.list[0].weather[0].description` should return the string value that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string first with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and then access the data with the properties.

```js
var json = '{ "cod": "200", "message": 0.0085, "cnt": 37, "list": [{ "dt": 1492074000, "main": { "temp": 8.74, "temp_min": 8.39, "temp_max": 8.74, "pressure": 1002.4, "sea_level": 1023.01, "grnd_level": 1002.4, "humidity": 94, "temp_kf": 0.35 }, "weather": [{ "id": 500, "main": "Rain", "description": "Lekki deszcz", "icon": "10d" }], "clouds": { "all": 32 } }] }',
    object = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(object.list[0]['weather'][0].description);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the call to the parsing function (`JSON.parse(json)`) before you start accessing the internals of the parsed object. Otherwise, you are trying to access properties like `'list'` on your json *string* instead of on the json *data structure*.

```js
var json = `{
  "cod": "200",
  "message": 0.0085,
  "cnt": 37,
  "list": [{
    "dt": 1492074000,
    "main": {
      "temp": 8.74,
      "temp_min": 8.39,
      "temp_max": 8.74,
      "pressure": 1002.4,
      "sea_level": 1023.01,
      "grnd_level": 1002.4,
      "humidity": 94,
      "temp_kf": 0.35
    },
    "weather": [{
      "id": 500,
      "main": "Rain",
      "description": "Lekki deszcz",
      "icon": "10d"
    }],
    "clouds": {
      "all": 32
    }
  }]
}`

console.log(
  JSON.parse(json).list[0]['weather'][0].description
)
```